# JSoup extracting values from <td> tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to extract values from `td` tag, but it doesn't work, one of `td` contains value which is called "Technology", and I want to get `td` value which is after him, for example `td` is 'Technology' and `td` which is after that: 'Windows Server' <- how can I get this value? here is a code:

```
</td>
   </tr>
      </tbody>
         </table>
       </dd>
      <dt>
      <a href="#course-info">Informacje o kursie</a></dt><dd id="course-info"><table><tbody>

<tr>
  <td>Odbiorcy:</td>
  <td style="text-transform: capitalize;">IT Professionals</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Technologia:</td><td>Windows Server</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Poziom:</td><td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Bieżąca wersja:</td><td>B</td>
</tr>
```

when I'm doing something like that:

```
for (Element element : doc.select("#course-info").first().children()){
        if(element.text().contains("Tech")){
            System.out.println(element.nextElementSibling().html());
        }
    }
```

Then NPE appears (element), but when I delete this loop, whole method works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific `CSS selector` for "Windows Server" is `#course-info > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)`.
If you want to know which selector to use, open your browser's developers tools (F12), and inspect the DOM. Select the desired element and get the selector.
I believe that you have more rows in your table, so you'll have to loop thru. the table, by changing one (or more) of the number constants in the above selector.